# Visual C++ 2013 does not indent after no brace statement

Tags: visual-studio-2013, indentation

I'm using Visual C++ Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. Before installing the last update, the indentation for blocks with no braces was wrong, for example:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
x += i;
```

Since after the last update, it is doing the right thing:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    x += i;
```

However, now, when I have two nested blocks, one with no brace and another with braces, it simply does not indent right:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
    x += i + j;
    ...
    }
```

If both blocks have no brace, it indents correctly.

I have tried all possible options and I was not able to correct it...

Comment: These settings are in "Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Formatting >> Indentation". Trying playing with those.

Comment: Please do wrap the inner for inside braces. You'll thank me in 6 months time!

Comment: Saving throw to prevent making an opinionated comment to this question...failed.  Please don't style your code this way. At a glance it's really hard to tell what statements are inside the loop's body.

Comment: @Cyber, I've already tried all of them.

Comment: @user3791372 This the style of code I use for more than 10 years. I'm not going to change right now. =D